# returning a reference to mapped char* from operator[]

Tags: c++

I have a data structure:

```
#include <map>

struct array{

    map<const char*, char*> data;   

    //constructor
    array(const char* key, char* value = ""){
        data.insert(pair<const char*, char*>(key, value));  
    }   

    //overloaded operator[] seems to be my problem
    char* operator[](const char* key) { return (char*)data[key]; }
};
```

now, without overloading the assignment `operator=`, I test-drove
it like this:

```
array var("first", "second");
var["third"] = "fourth";          //and my compiler (gcc) is angry about this
```

Now, my compiler returned the following error:

> functions.cpp:13:18: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Question: is there anything am failing to understand? How can I
return the address of `map::data["key"]` from `operator[]`,
so that `var["third"] = "fourth";` works properly?  Mind you, I don't want to do this with c++'s string type. strictly `char*`.

Comment: I really suggest you use `std::string` if you are using strings.

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks ! but is it impossible without std::string ? i really wish to do it through char*

Comment: It would be a lot easier.

Comment: Do you didn't want to write `typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> array;` then and go home early?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there anything am failing to understand?

You are returning the pointer by value. That means the caller will receive a copy of the pointer. The caller cannot make changes to the pointer within the map, using a *copy* of the pointer in the map.

> how can i return the address of map::data["key"] from operator[], so that var["third"] = "fourth"; works properly ?

Return a reference to it:

```
char*& operator[](const char* key) { /* ... */ }
```

In order for that to work, you need to get rid of the redundant cast:

```
return data[key];
```

---

Another problem in your program is that you store non-const `char*` in your map but you initialize those pointers with string literals, which are `const`. Such conversion is illegal in c++11, which means that your program is ill-formed. Even before c++11, such conversion has been deprecated since standard c++ has existed.

The danger of doing this is that you may accidentally modify const string through the non-const pointer, which would result in undefined behaviour.

Solution: Use `const char*` pointers in the map, if the modification of the string contents is not needed. If modification *is* needed, then instead point to separately allocated `char` arrays that are copied from the string literals. The simplest way to do the latter is to use `std::string` as the value type, but if you don't want to do that, then you can manage the arrays yourself.

---

Third problem in your program is that you appear to assume that `var["third"]` is guaranteed to find a key that was initialized with `"third"`. That assumption is wrong. Separate - but identical - string literals are not guaranteed to have the same address.

Solution: Use `std::string` as the key, or use custom a comparison functor that compares the strings based on their content. Hint: Use `std::strcmp` to implement the functor.

---

P.S. you don't appear to have any overloads for `operator[](...)`, so it's not "*overloaded*".

Answer (score 2):

> is there anything am failing to understand ?

Yes, I think you're confused about your code and its intention. In strict terms, the answer is that you're trying to use an `rvalue` in a place where only `lvalues` are allowed, i.e. on the lhs of an assignment. To fix that immediate problem, you would need to change your operator to:

```
char*& operator[](const char* key) { return data[key]; }
```

(i.e. returning a reference to the pointer contained in the map).
This would compile, but I don't think this structure would do what you want it to. For example, modifying the contents strings of map's entries like this:

```
var["third"][0] = 'a';
```

would be undefined behaviour if you used string literals to populate it, as you do in your example.

Better to take the advice of the commenters and switch to using `std::strings`.

Answer (score 1):

To make it compile you would have to change your operator[] signature to:

```
char*& operator[](const char* key) { return data[key]; }
```

but then you will get warnings and possible UB, as string literal is const array, while you want to assign it to non const `char*`. To silence those warning you would have to make additional changes, all `char*` to `const char*`:

```
struct array{

    std::map<const char*, const char*> data;   

    //constructor
    array(const char* key, const char* value = ""){
        data.insert(std::pair<const char*, const char*>(key, value));  
    }   

    //overloaded operator[] seems to be my problem
    const char*& operator[](const char* key) { return data[key]; }

};
```

But maybe this is not what you want.

The best solution is to switch your `std::map<const char*, char*>` to `std::map<std::string, std::string>`

Comment: I would not suggest `std::map<const char*, std::string>` to the OP.  The will be sorting by the address contained in the pointer and not the string value.

Comment: @NathanOliver good point, actually sorting by address should work but then why use std::map

Comment: @user2079303 thanks ! your comment really inspired me. i must admit am stupid. but then, one reason i dont like to use std::map<const char*, std::string> is that, i only need my map's keys to be const, not the value pairs. and std:: string will not gurantee me of that as c_str() will cast to const char* if i do: var["third"]. besides, i need speed, and want to avoid the overhead of std::string's construction.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie (wrong nick - but no problem:-) ) With c++11 we have move semantics which makes std::string ultra fast.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie did you comment on the wrong question, or tag the wrong name? Anyway, I don't quite understand what you're saying. What does `std:: string` not guarantee? What do you mean by saying that `c_str()` "casts" to const char* and why is it a problem? Anyway, if you *need speed*, then don't forget to *measure* whether `std::string` actually has significant overhead.

Comment: sorry about that user2079303, that answer wasn't meant for you but @Smeeheey. nevertheless, whether or not std::string is ultra fast, even if its a 0.00000001 ms avoidance of constructor call, that to me is a positive contribution to speed.

Comment: @OsagieOdigie keeping `const char*` as key in your map might cause unexpected results as @user2079303 has pointed out, using <string,string> does results in more code (actually twice : https://godbolt.org/g/VjIXmx), but does not suffer from this problem